# key.properties flutter APK build

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, build

I followed the instructions [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android) Exactly.

this is my key.properties file:
[image]
this is my build.gradle file:
[image]
this is the error:
[image]
I even printed the file value and it is still wrong and not working. I tried the suggestions in the similar questions but they are not working for me.

Comment: First of all you have to post code and not images, secondly is a good approach to accept answers where the people helps you.. That is the purpose of SO, helping community like you and like you other people the days will come will see the answers. If you accept one of those you help others. Understood??

Comment: I added picture instead of code because I wanted my work tree to be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the <> from storeFile and
you already pointing to the folder just need the file name
should be something like this

storeFile = key.jks

Comment: just put the .jks name without path

Comment: you already pointing to the folder just need the file name

Answer (score 4):

First of all remove “<” and “>” then the path needs double backslashes as follows (the absolute path it's ok):

```
storeFile=C:\\Users\\YourUser\\OtherFolder\\ProjectPath\\somefilekey.jks
```

after that in your build.gradle file you have to use as follows:

```
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}


android {

    compileSdkVersion 30

  //…...

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
  //OR ……..
        debug {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

   //…….


}
```